# Azure Pipelines App Slack notification not working

Tags: slack, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I hope somebody can help me with this issue.

I recently moved my azure pipeline `approval release` process from slack web hook to Azure pipeline App for slack, because I found that having the `approve` and `reject` button directly in slack chat was something really nice to have to make approvals easier.

This is the process I follow:

- Install Azure pipeline App in slack workspace
- Create a private channel and `/invite @azpipelines`
- I signed in `/azpipelines signing`

Once those steps has been completed, I started to subscribe my release pipelines selecting the stages I was interesting in. Everything worked just fine for a couple of days, I was receiving the notifications and I was able to approve and reject them without any problem, which is great, but today, out of nowhere I realised that I was receiving the emails from azpipelines that a release has been issued but no notification in channel.

The documentation about azure pipeline is really poor and I have no idea what is going wrong with the configuration.

Did this happen to anyone before and can direct me on the right path of what could be the issue behind it?

Thank you very much for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I also could encounter the similar problems.

And many times, I can fix the issue via the following ways:

- Unsubscribe and re-subscribe the notifications.
- Log out and then log in again.
- Uninstall and re-install the Azure Pipelines App.

May be you also can try this steps to see if the issue can be resolved.